I get quota pop-up for /, even though timeshift is a different mount
I'm getting a popup saying 'The volume "Filesystem root" has only x disk space remaining", like below:

When I click Examine to open Disk Usage Analyzer, it is timeshift that is taking up the most space. Except the timeshift folder is on a different mount than /. On the larger mount that the timeshift folder is on, there is plenty of space. Multiple gigabytes.
Here is the output of df -h:
user@hostname:/$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           594M  1.6M  592M   1% /run
/dev/sda6        46G   42G  1.3G  98% /
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7       720G  141G  542G  21% /mnt/data
/dev/sda1       256M  117M  140M  46% /boot/efi
tmpfs           594M   64K  594M   1% /run/user/1000

How do I get my system to stop giving me a false positive for the disk quota?
This is on Linux Mint 20.

It is more likely that it is you that has misunderstood where the disk is being used, than it is that the OS is lying to you. Can you show the output of df -h and possibly also show exactly what the popup is saying and what the disk analyzer is showing? If you have enabled disk quotas, then it would be good to know how you did that too.

That df -h clearly shows that you are about to run out of space on /. There's no separate mount for Timeshift.

Looks like the snapshots under the /timeshift folder are old snapshots. I guess timeshift stops tracking them because I changed timeshift to store on /mnt/data?

You haven't adjusted your timeshift configuration yet (or you have, incorrectly), so it's trying to save on /.
